# Lubuntu 14.04 Sylpheed email retrieves old deleted mail

Tags: lubuntu, email, sylpheed

Just installed Lubuntu 14.04 on a Dell Dimension 4700. On Sylpheed email when I retrieve mail It retrieves old deleted email from more than two (2) years ago. Is there a particular way to set it to where it won't retrieve old deleted mail? Thank you!

Comment: You are receiving old mail because they are still on your mail server. If you do another fresh install, you will receive all the mail again, unless you change the settings in sylpheed to delete the mail once you downloaded it. I can look up for you how to do that, but I have to know if your account is a pop account or something else?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. OK, It's a Gmail account if that helps for now. I can look as soon as I get home.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are receiving the mail (again) because on your last system, you must have unchecked "remove messages on the server after download". In Sylpheed, you can do that in `settings > accountsettings`:

[image]

As you can see in this `pop account` example, you can do that by checking the option ("remove messages after x days", make it `0` to remove immediately).

If you use Gmail, you can use it as a pop account as wel for convenience reasons, with the same settings options.

[image]

**Additional information:**

If you make the settings as above, the email will not be downloaded again via your `pop` account, not even on a fresh install. However, they will continue to be available using Gmail in your webbrowser, unless you change some settings on the Gmail website. If you want to completely remove the mail you downloaded via your `pop` account, go to the Gmail website, click on the settings icon (the gear wheel in the top right of the window) and change the settings in the `pop` section to

`if the messages are opened with pop, remove Gmail copy` (*see below*)

[image]

Comment: I'll do that! Thanks again! I'll let you know the results. By the way, once I do the set-up, will have to delete the old messages again?

Comment: @MoRenteria That depends on the situation, if you did not remove them from the server, the will appear again when you create a new account :). BUT the next time you install, they won't.

Comment: OK, I'll do that :)